# Installing pypiwin32 with cmd

Tags: python, windows, cmd, pypi

I've installed `pypiwin32` but when I run it on cmd it doesn't recognize it as a command and I get the error: `"pypiwin is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

[image]

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish with it running in the command prompt?

Comment: I want to run this `pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew`

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why you are trying to run pypiwin32 as a cmd command but you would want to do:

```
python -m pypiwin32
```

Comment: That gives me `No module named pypiwin32`

Comment: You should physically check where your python libs are at do `python -m site` it should print out where your python libraries are go to `site-packages` and check if pypiwin32 is installed. If no use pip to uninstall it and reinstall it again.

Comment: @FacundoSchiavoni `win32api` or `win32com`